# ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 156: Can't create table 'db1.testtable' (errno: 121)

Tags: mysql

I am restoring all databases from a mysqldump file and am getting the following error:

```
ERROR 1005 (HY000) at line 156: Can't create table 'db1.testtable' (errno: 121)
```

As my SQL has been created from the mysqldump utility, I am confused how an error has appeared in the SQL code!

The relevant lines in my dump.sql are:

```
CREATE TABLE `testtable` (
  `username` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `emailaddress` varchar(255) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks, Jim

Answer (score 8):

errno 121 means a duplicate key error. Probably the table already exists in the InnoDB internal data dictionary, though the .frm file for the table has been deleted. This is the most common reason for getting errno 121 in table creation. Another possible reason is a name conflict in a foreign key constraint name. Constraint names must be unique in a database, like table names are.

What does InnoDB print in the .err log?

Comment: 111013  9:30:47  InnoDB: Error: table `db1`.`testtable` already exists in InnoDB internal
InnoDB: data dictionary. Have you deleted the .frm file
InnoDB: and not used DROP TABLE? Have you used DROP DATABASE
InnoDB: for InnoDB tables in MySQL version <= 3.23.43?
InnoDB: See the Restrictions section of the InnoDB manual.
InnoDB: You can drop the orphaned table inside InnoDB by
InnoDB: creating an InnoDB table with the same name in another
InnoDB: database and copying the .frm file to the current database.
InnoDB: Then MySQL thinks the table exists, and DROP TABLE will
InnoDB: succeed.

Comment: @user993052 I think those instructions are pretty clear ! :-)

Comment: **bold**Error: table db1.testtable already exists in InnoDB internal InnoDB: data dictionary.**bold**
I'm assuming we are talking about the ibdata1, ib_logfile0, ib_logfile1 files? I'll try deleting them and starting the load from dump.sql from scratch.

Comment: it tells you how to fix it too .. create the same table in another database copy the .frm file then use DROP TABLE to remove it ....

Comment: @user993052 dont delete files - use the commands in MYSQL to remove the tables / database - thats why you got into this mess in the first place !